# Is it necessary to call `unmountComponentAtNode` if the component's container is removed?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I render a React component `SettingsTab` within a wrapper called `TeamView`. Its API looks something like

```
class TeamView {
  constructor() {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  render() {
    ReactDOM.render(<SettingsTab/>, this.el);
    return this;
  }

  remove() {
    this.el.remove(); 
  }
}
```

used something like

```
// to present the team view
const teamView = new TeamView();
document.body.appendChild(teamView.render().el);

// to remove the team view
teamView.remove();
```

And what I'm wondering is, **should `TeamView#remove` call `ReactDOM. unmountComponentAtNode(this.el)` before calling `this.el.remove()`**?

The examples I can find around the web make it seem like `unmountComponentAtNode` only needs to be called if the container is going to remain in the DOM; and the new [portals example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals) just removes the container, without calling `unmountComponentAtNode`.

But, I'm not sure if that's special because it's using a portal, and [this post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html) makes it kind of seem like it's always good practice to call `unmountComponentAtNode`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is important to call `unmountComponentAtNode()` because if you don't do this, none of the components below in the tree will know they have been unmounted.

User-defined components often do something in `componentDidMount` that creates a reference to the tree from the global environment. For example, you may add a `window` event handler (which isn't managed by React), a Redux store subscription, a `setInterval` call, etc. All of this is fine and normal as long as these bindings are removed in `componentWillUnmount`.

However, **if you just remove the root from the DOM but never call `unmountComponentAtNode`, React will have no idea the components in that tree need to be unmounted**. Since their `componentWillUnmount` never fires, those subscriptions stay, and prevent the whole tree from getting garbage collected.

So for all practical purposes you should always unmount the root if you're going to remove that container node. Otherwise you'll most likely get a memory leak—if not now, then later when some of your components (potentially deep in the tree, maybe even from third-party libraries) add subscriptions in their `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I have an odd use case where I am hydrating a child component of an existing react tree. would I still need to unmount it manually? asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786709/how-can-you-properly-use-hydrate-and-or-hydrateroot-inside-of-an-existing-reac

Comment: Just a follow up, I imagine the answer is yes (I should unmount it manually) but I have run into odd errors when doing so, such as https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22343 (more detailed in my above link)

Comment: Is it okay to unmount after removing the root's element from the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

Even though you called `this.el.remove()`, you should still call the `unmountComponentAtNode(this.el)` because `unmountComponentAtNode` will  clean up its event handlers and state, but the `remove` method will not.

For example, Eventhough you have clicked to remove the div, you can still call it's click event handlers:

```js
var tap = document.querySelector('.tap');
var other = document.querySelector('.other');
tap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(tap.getAttribute('data-name') + ' has been clicked');
  tap.remove();
});

other.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  tap.click();
});
```

```html
<div class="tap" data-name="tap">First Click me to remove me</div>
<div class="other">Then Click me </div>
```

Comment: That's interesting @jiangangxiong, thanks especially for the code snippet! I'll note that the user wouldn't be able to trigger these handlers after the element was removed, and it's generally uncommon in React to keep a programmatic reference to a DOM element. (Our code does not do so.) So do you know if _React_ keeps any "global" references to handlers/state, if `unmountComponentAtNode` was not called? Otherwise the handlers/state would be unreachable after `remove` was called, so the garbage collector would clean that stuff up.

Comment: For example, the `empty()` of  jQuery, to avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the  elements before removing the elements themselves. Why？In some situation (particularly on IE) where neither the DOM element nor the event handler and state can get cleaned up because they're each causing the other to stick around ( memory leak). jQuery helps we avoid this, but we should do it ourself if without jQuery. And the `unmountComponentAtNode` did the same as `empty` of jQuery. So it's a good practice to always unbind the event handlers and state.

Comment: Hm @jiangangxiong, IMO that behavior makes sense for a library like jQuery since it's supporting old browsers, and it's easy to internalize the cost of the extra logic inside the library. However if I'm not using such an abstraction, I'd like to avoid extra code if possible. And I'm only supporting modern browsers. I'd also like to hear why [the React portal example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals) doesn't call `unmountComponentAtNode`.

So, thanks for the added information but I'm still looking to hear best practices for React specifically.

Comment: @JiangangXiong The issue is I can't get the reactDOM equivalent of my component. For example - ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(
            document.getElementsByTagName('ans-comments')
     );

Answer (score 3):

I asked this question in the [#react-internals](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/148818842779385856) Discord channel and received the following response:

[image: answer to question]

So, this tallies with what @jiangangxiong says above: as long as we

- don't keep our own references to component DOM elements
- nor attach event handlers outside of React
- and only need to support modern browsers

we should only need to `remove` the container to have the component's event handlers and state garbage collected, no need to call `unmountComponentAtNode`.

Comment: This is technically correct but there's a huge pitfall that you might miss: these restrictions apply to **all components in the tree**. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198011/458193