# How can you properly use hydrate (and/or hydrateRoot) inside of an existing React tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this accurate code for properly hydrating code that is created e.g. during a useEffect?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { hydrate, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom'


export default function ({ html }: { html: string }) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const domNode = ref.current
    if (domNode) {
      if (domNode.innerHTML) {
        unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
      }

      domNode.innerHTML = html
      hydrate(<MyComponent />, domNode)
    }
    return () => {
      if (domNode) {
        unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
      }
    }
  }, [html])

  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

I know this is a weird pattern, but basically we are performing "SSR" from a webworker, that is the context for this odd approach

however, this has produced a number of odd errors including

```
Warning: render(...): It looks like the React-rendered content of this container was removed without using React. This is not supported and will cause errors. Instead, call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode to empty a container.
```

I have also seen other rare errors like

```
Node.removeChild: The node to be removed is not a child of this node
```

and

```
Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by another copy of React.
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix for "Warning: render(...): It looks like the React-rendered content of this container was removed without using React. This is not supported and will cause errors. Instead, call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode to empty a container." error: use a setTimeout,0 from following clue from this comment https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22343#issuecomment-924098716 which let me know, the current tree should unmount before you unmount your hydrated tree

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { hydrate, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom'


export default function ({ html }: { html: string }) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const domNode = ref.current
    if (domNode) {
      if (domNode.innerHTML) {
        unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
      }

      domNode.innerHTML = html
      hydrate(<MyComponent />, domNode)
    }
    return () => {
        // use setTimeout to try to avoid error :unmounted component rendered
        // by another copy of react error, even when that is not the case. See
        // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22343#issuecomment-924098716
        setTimeout(() => {
          unmountComponentAtNode(domNode)
        }, 0)
    }
  }, [html])

  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```